Encoded result gives output as bolean instead of numeric
After performing OneHotEncoding, my data frame gives values for its columns as True and False, not as 1 and 0, what I am supposed to have. My code looks like this, where the data frame is ds and the categorical column name is "type":
pd.get_dummies(ds,columns = ["type"])

I'm trying to get a numeric result.

pd.get_dummies(ds, columns=["type"]).astype(int)

bool_val = True
print(bool_val)       # returns True
print(int(bool_val))  # returns 1


For whoever downvoted: please feel free to explain why. The OP is getting values back as logical, and wants them binary 0/1; casting is the easiest way to do that.

I didn't downvote but even the question is unclear. What is meant with "binary" here? If we're talking about a simple integer, then there is no need to convert it, since True is an integer. isinstance(True, int) will give you True and this means that e.g. True + 2 will give you a result of 3.
